# Are there any open source Windows 10 TaskManager replacement?

Tags: open-source, windows-10

Are there any open source project that is like "C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe" on Windows 10?

The feature include the list of system processes and resource they are using,and real time statistics of system resource occupation e.g. CPU/disk IO/network IO/memory.

There seems to be no open source projects about this that have enough feature to replace the build in one.

It's better if it is a library to get the above system information and we can develop UI/tools based on it.

Comment: Your question seems to ask for general discussion instead of a specific alternative. Read the tour/help for what this site is about: software recommendations. Then [edit] (or delete) your question.

Comment: I first posted it on StackOverflow and people there tell me to post it here.Then where can I post it now?My need is clear:are there such open source project or library?If yes,what are they?If no,question done.

Comment: Then (again) rewrite your question so that it clearly is asking for a software recommendation and leave the irrelevant texts out. You don't start with "How to write...", that is off topic here. Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you may be able to copy the task manager from a ReactOS image/installation.

Comment: @ QwertyChouskie can you provide a link? I think ROS is dead....

Comment: Not Open Source _but freeware_ it is well worth looking at Sysinternals Process Explorer (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Answer (score 1):

Daphne is one that comes in mind http://www.drk.com.ar/daphne.php

> Daphne is a small (system tray) application for killing, controlling
>   and debugging Windows' processes. It was born to kill a Windows
>   process and became almost a task manager replacement. You can kill a
>   process by dragging the mouse over the windows, by right-clicking the
>   process in the main process list, or by typing its name with the "Kill
>   all by name" command. You can set a any window to be always on top, to
>   be transparent, to be enable, et cetera.

Source code can be found here http://www.drk.com.ar/daphne.php#Contribute and the license is *GNU General Public License*.

[image]

Comment: Does it support real time process IO occupation and system resource utilization?That's my main need-----to figure out quickly at any time why my computer is slow(CPU/memory/disk 100% and which process is the source of problem)

Answer (score 1):

Here comes my obligatory [python](https://www.python.org/) answer:

There is a python library called [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) which gives you full programmatic access to the running processes, *and a lot more*, from the command line or [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

- Open Source - **BSD Licence**
- List Processes & Resources **Yes**
- Allow you to write your own UI **Yes**
- Also allows control of processes.
- Not just Windows **Windows, macOS, Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Solaris, AIX**
- 32 & 64 bit
- There are a number of projects which add a GUI to it
- Nice [documentation](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- Lots of other functionality.

```
In [1]: import psutil

In [2]: proc = psutil.Process()

In [3]: pd = proc.as_dict()

In [4]: pd.keys()
Out[4]: dict_keys(['cmdline', 'memory_full_info', 'num_threads', 'username', 'name', 'num_handles', 'open_files', 'memory_percent', 'pid', 'create_time', 'memory_maps', 'connections', 'exe', 'nice', 'cpu_times', 'environ', 'ionice', 'cwd', 'io_counters', 'cpu_percent', 'num_ctx_switches', 'threads', 'cpu_affinity', 'memory_info', 'ppid', 'status'])

In [5]: proc.exe()
Out[5]: 'C:\\python36_64\\python.exe'

In [6]: proc.memory_full_info()
Out[6]: pfullmem(rss=71438336, vms=61792256, num_page_faults=36033, peak_wset=71516160, wset=71438336, peak_paged_pool=190608, paged_pool=190312, peak_nonpaged_pool=43952, nonpaged_pool=41648, pagefile=61792256, peak_pagefile=61939712, private=61792256, uss=64483328)
```

It can even handle Windows services:

```
In [7]: services = list(psutil.win_service_iter())

In [8]: services
[<WindowsService(name='ABBYY.Licensing.ScreenshotReader.Windows.11.0', display_name='ABBYY Screenshot Reader 11 - Licensing Service') at 1163743151384>,

 <WindowsService(name='AJRouter', display_name='AllJoyn Router Service') at 1163743153008>,
 <WindowsService(name='ALG', display_name='Application Layer Gateway Service') at 1163743151832>,
 <WindowsService(name='AMD External Events Utility', display_name='AMD External Events Utility') at 1163743153904>,
 <WindowsService(name='AppIDSvc', display_name='Application Identity') at 1163743152504>,
 <WindowsService(name='Appinfo', display_name='Application Information') at 1163743151496>,
 <WindowsService(name='AppMgmt', display_name='Application Management') at 1163743152000>,
...................

In [10]: s = services[0]                                                                                        

In [11]: s.name(), s.pid()                                                                                     
Out[11]: ('ABBYY.Licensing.ScreenshotReader.Windows.11.0', 4508)                                               

In [12]: sp = psutil.Process(4508)                                                                             

In [13]: sp.cpu_percent()                                                                                      
Out[13]: 0.0                                                                                                   

In [14]: sp.cmdline()                                                                                          
Out[14]:                                                                                                       
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\ABBYY\\ScreenshotReader\\11.00\\Licensing\\NetworkLicenseServer.exe', 
 '-service']
```